# Corrplot not producing an actual plot?

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I'm running the below R script, and it once produced a plot for the corrplot call, but hasn't actually produced it since.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
data(ChemicalManufacturingProcess)

df <- ChemicalManufacturingProcess

dim(df)#there are 106 null values across 176 rows. This would disrupt the dataset. Let's impute after running a correlation.
str(df) #all numerical
summary(df)#let's find and fix na's
colSums(is.na(df))
sum(is.na(df))

library(corrplot)

m = cor(df)
corrplot::corrplot(m, method = 'number', col = 'black', cl.pos = 'n')
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code (it takes some time) it looks like this:

```
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
data(ChemicalManufacturingProcess)

df <- ChemicalManufacturingProcess

dim(df)#there are 106 null values across 176 rows. This would disrupt the dataset. Let's impute after running a correlation.
str(df) #all numerical
summary(df)#let's find and fix na's
colSums(is.na(df))
sum(is.na(df))

library(corrplot)

m = cor(df)
corrplot::corrplot(m, method = 'number', col = 'black', cl.pos = 'n')
```

Output:

[image]

What you can try is restart your environment and reinstall the packages and try again.

Please note: you have a lot of features so that is why your plot looks like this.